# Double buffering with excanvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, excanvas

What is a workaround available for implementing double buffering by using the explorer canvas library.?

ie. I want to implement like this

SourceImage -> Canvas1 -> Canvas2

- Draw the source Image into the background hidden canvas . Canvas1
- Draw the actual canvas from the background canvas.

How can implement this behavior using explorer canvas?

Answer (score 0):

No way I think, since excanvas uses VML technology to draw shapes and images in IE, which is vector-based. So you can not prerender it.